# Elementary converge and diverge

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

Why does the geometric series $\sum^{\infty}_{j=0}c^j$ converge when $|c|<1$, but diverge when $|c|\ge 1$? Since the geometric series is $= \frac{1}{1-c}$, which means it is undefined at $c=1$, but then why would $c>1$ make it diverge for? Isn't it just altering the sign of the limit to negative to positive?

Comment: It sounds like you may be interested in reading about [analytic continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation). The sum $\sum_{j=0}^\infty c^j$ and the function $\frac{1}{1-c}$ agree **where they both make sense**, but $\frac{1}{1-c}$ makes sense on a strictly larger domain than does the sum.

Comment: Q, does it make any sense to you that you could add up infinitely many positive numbers, and get a negative answer? $1+2+4+8+\cdots=-1$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson No, of course not, but why did you ask that?

Comment: Q, it's the case $c=2$ of your question. You asked whether it is "just altering the sign of the limit to negative to positive" which I took to mean you had no problem with $\sum_0^{\infty}2^j=1/(1-2)=-1$ --- or at any rate, that you are asking, what's wrong with that chain of equations. So, part of what's wrong with it is it makes a sum of positive numbers negative.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ops, I didn't mean it to be taken that way. I should have been more careful of my choice of words. What I meant was if you had values $c<1$ then it will be all positive numbers where $c>1$ will be negative, which is what I meant of "altering signs".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a series converges, the terms must converge to zero. Since $|c^j| = |c|^j$, if $|c| \geq 1$, then the terms do not converge to zero, hence the series does not converge.

If $|c|<1$, then it is easy to see that $\sum_{j=0}^n c^j = \frac{1-c^{n+1}}{1-c}$, and $\lim_n c^n = 0$, hence the series converges.

Comment: As an aside, I think of diverging as $|\sum_n|\to \infty$. If $c=e^{i\theta}$, then the partial sum remains bounded, but does not converge.

Comment: When you say $|c|<1$ do you mean any number less than $1$ or the circle centered at $0$ with radius strictly less than $1$?

Comment: Any number whose absolute value is less than 1, so the latter if $\mathbb{C}$, and $(-1,1)$ if $\mathbb{R}$.